# Reduce watches created by ui-grid or alternative grid solutions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

Apologies if this is a repeated question about ui-grid but I could do with being clear on the options for my particular use case.  Other similar questions don't conclusively answer my problem.

We are attempting to use ui-grid in a fairly unusual web application where the number of tables on the page is effectively limitless.  They get added the more activity the user does.  Not ideal but that is what is required.

When using ui-grid, even with a fairly small simple table, it is adding around 1000 watches for each table. And the digest cycle increases significantly with each table being added too.  This leads to poor performance when the number of tables increases, as you might expect.

My question is then, is there anything that can be done with ui-grid to reduce these number of watches? i.e. without delving in to the source code to make changes.  We are passing our data in to the ui-grid directive using one-time binding notation, but that makes no difference.  From looking at other similar questions, it would seem to me that there is nothing else that can be done, which might well imply that ui-grid is not suitable for us.

Alternatively, is there a way within AngularJs to prevent two way binding within a directive?  I'm not aware of such a method, but perhaps someone knows a trick to make this happen?!

Finally, can anyone suggest an alternative grid that would be a better fit for our use case?  We are trialling ui-grid due to the functionality it provides, such as column selection, cell formatting, ordering, filtering and so on.  Are there better performing AngularJS or other JS grids out there that would cover this functionality? Preferably free to use? Others we've considered checking out are Kendo UI, jqxGrid, ag-grid (though perhaps this needs to be paid for).

Any help is massively appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 1):

My company has run into similar issues though not with ui-grid specifically. You've probably already considered this but the fix for us was horizontal and vertical paging. I don't know much about your use case, but we realized that horizontal and vertical scrolling with a huge grid had the same issues you are running into, but it wasn't really any more functional for the user to use a scroll bar than to use page controls to move between blocks of the grid. At most 500 cells would fit on a single screen at a time and it was very easy to lose your place trying to use a scroll bar.

By doing this we're able to use 1 way bindings (probably with bind-once but I would have to dig into the code to be sure). Even with two way binding the same technique should work for you too if it works with your use case.

Answer (score 1):

if you us ag-Grid, there will be no watches. ag-Grid doesn't use Angular at it's core, so doesn't have watches internally.

ag-Grid has two versions, free and enterprise. if you don't need the enterprise features, then use the free versions.